# Linear mix model to get the correlation

Tags: matlab, statistics

I want to calculate the correlation between A and B. For A or B, the data is 7*12=84, which represent that there are 7 subjects, and 12 values from each subject. Because there may be some correlation between the 12 values since it comes from one subject, the corr function in matlab is not suitable.

Then, I find that the matlab provides the function [fitlme](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/stats/fitlme.html), which is an implement of linear mixed model. The function seems can solve my problem. But I don't know how to read the result. Where is the value of correlation?

Comment: The [documentation](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/stats/fitlme.html) says "*it returns **lme** as a [LinearMixedModel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmixedmodel-class.html) object*.  The documentation for the object ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmixedmodel-class.html)) says it has the *Covariance of the estimated fixed-effects coefficients* as a *p*-by-*p* matrix stored as **CoefficientCovariance**.  Isn't the correlation available from the covariance matrix ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-correlationmatrix.html))?

Comment: It is the coefficient covariance of random effects. I don't think it is the correlation coefficient between A and B.

Comment: Ah, you're probably right.

Comment: Actually, I find there may be no correlation coefficient in the linear mixed model. I think we should notice two parameters in the linear mixed model: the p value and the slope.